# Effect of camera pose on measurements

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration

I'm doing some experimentation with OpenCV calibrateCamera,trying to figure out how much changing the pose of my camera affects my measurements.
For example I have a 16mm focal length lens, and a 400 mm working distance. I calibrate the camera using a checkerboard pattern and calibrateCamera. Then I grab an image containing two fiducials, transform the locations of the fiducials to real world coordinates and I calculate the distance between the fiducials to be 10mm.

Now, if I move the camera in the x or y axis, not changing my working distance my readings should be the same correct?(assuming I am correcting for distortion)
If I move in the z direction my 10 mm reading will change. Can I calculate the 'error' introduced by changing my working distance by just looking at the ratios of object size to working distance? e.g. 10mm/400mm = .025, if I move my camera farther away from the object by 1mm then 10mm/401mm = 0.02494, so I can predict a measurement of around .02494 * 400 = 9.936mm.?
What about a more complicated scenario? What if I move the camera back by 5mm and up by 5mm, so there is now effectively a tilt. Can I calculate what this error would be? I'm just trying to figure out how much the pose of my camera can change before I need to recalibrate.

Comment: sounds about correct. you can reduce this all to a 2D case of similar triangles/[Intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem)

Comment: Have a look at the projection process. Basically you could formulate a parametric transformation matrix with alpha, beta, gamma rotation angles and tx, ty, tz translation vector of your camera. For every object point you can compute the offset between transformed and untransforned projected pixel positions and randomly or systematically test different parameters.

Comment: @Micka If I have calibrated my entire FOV I guess x,y translation will not matter? But z translation will cause perspective error as will rotation. How can I measure this error? I can take a real world point and calc the projection onto the sensor using the intrinsic and extrinsic matrices. But say I add a 10 degree z rotation and project these points that are 10mm apart, how do I know how much error that has introduced?

Comment: L2 Norm of ReferenceProjection(x,y,z) - CorruptedProjection(x,y,z) is the error for a single 3D point.